# How to Run a JS Method at Every Navigate in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular project, when i navigate the page to another page, there will be a problem in the page.

**The 3rd javascript libraries i have added are broken when be navigated.**

So i have to run this code.

```
declare var MY_LIBRARY: any;// referencing jQuery library

MY_LIBRARY.initAllPlugins();
```

I have to run this code at every navigate.

**How to do run this method when page navigated ?**

Is there a middleware system or something like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for Route changes like this:

```js
export class SomeComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router) {
        router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
                // do sth.
            }

            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                // do sth.
            }

            if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
                // do sth.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But keep in mind that running code (especially initializing some plugins) on each navigation/Route change could be expensive and have impact on the performance of your application.

Comment: Your code works well when i type it in app.component.ts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would put any component code that needs to run when the component initializes into the OnInit method:

ngOnInit() {
     //Your init code here
  }

In your case I would be looking at the javascript libraries you're running and seeing if there aren't Angular versions you can use instead, or a better way to reference the libraries - perhaps in a singleton service that persists regardless of which component is loaded.

What you're suggesting here feels very heavy handed which suggests there's a much cleaner way to solve the root problem.